# mmap() owning memory block

Tags: c, linux, unix, mmap

I have a call to mmap() which I try to map 64MB using `MAP_ANONYMOUS` as follows:

```
void *block = mmap(0, 67108864, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
if (block == MAP_FAILED)
    exit(1);
```

I understand that to actually own the memory, I need to hit that block of memory. I want to add some sort of 0's or empty strings to actually own the memory. How would I do that? I tried the following, but that obviously segfaults (I know why it does):

```
char *temp = block;
for (int i = 0; i < 67108864; i++) {
    *temp = '0';
    temp++;
}
```

How would I actually gain ownership of that block by assigning something in that block?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by _own the memory_? after you use mmap, it returns a pointer (which you are assigning to block) Then you can change anything in that memory map, by simple pointer based operation. Your second code snippet would fill zeroes in the entire memory map, you have got using mmap.

Comment: You should do `{perror("mmap"); exit(EXIT_FAIOLURE);}` instead of just `exit(1)` when `mmap` fails. Because you need to understand *why* you `mmap` call fails.

Comment: Hi, do you mean that the memory will `alloc-on-write`? it won't really alloc a real memory block. And will delay it until you first write on it. So you want to make sure that memory has been allocaed?

Comment: Is you question related to memory overcommit? If it is, please say that explicitly!

Comment: What makes you think that the process does not own the memory zone it has obtained thru `mmap` ??

Comment: As Michael said, I want to make the memory resident. The above code segfaults when attempting to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your process already owns the memory, but what I think you want is to make it resident.  That is, you want the kernel to allocate physical memory for the `mmap`ed region.

The kernel allocates a virtual memory area (VMA) for the process, but this just specifies a valid region and doesn't actually allocate physical pages (or frames as they are also sometimes called).  To make the kernel allocate entries in the page table, all you need to do is force a page fault.

The easiest way to force a page fault is to touch the memory just like you're doing. Though, because your page size is almost certainly 4096 bytes, you really only need to read one byte every 4096 bytes thereby reducing the amount of work you actually need to do.

Finally, because you are setting the pages `PROT_READ`, you will actually want to read from each page rather than try to write.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I meant/need. So I tried changing my loop to i += 4096 and that still segfaults. I changed it to PROT_WRITE. How would you go about touching the memory?

Comment: Just writing a byte every page is fine.  Once you've set permission to `PROT_WRITE`, your code shouldn't segfault anymore.  If you just want to have read permission, then loading a byte per page into a variable will work.

Comment: Thet whould bring each page into memory, but that would not keep the OS to free it at some point. think of a machine with 63MB: your last touch would probably unload the first block... You should not do that. It's in the OS responsibility to make it available when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very well formulated. I don't understand **why you think the process is not owning its memory obtained thru `mmap`**?

Your newly `mmap`-ed memory zone has only `PROT_READ` (so you can just read the zeros inside) and you need that to be `PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE` to be able to write inside.

But your process already "owns" the memory once the `mmap` returned.

If the process has pid 1234, you could sequentially read (perhaps with `cat /proc/1234/maps` in a different terminal) its memory map thru `/proc/1234/maps`; from  inside your process, use `/proc/self/maps`.

Maybe you are interested in [memory overcommit](http://maboelnour.wordpress.com/2011/09/16/memory-overcommit-in-linux-memory-management/); there is a way to disable that.

Perhaps the [mincore(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mincore.2.html), [msync(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/msync.2.html), [mlock(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mlock.2.html) syscalls are interesting you.

Maybe you want the `MAP_POPULATE` or `MAP_LOCKED` flag of [mmap(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html)

<sup>I actually don't understand why you say "own the memory" in your question, which I don't understand very well. If you just want to disable memory overcommit, please tell.</sup>

And you might also `mmap` some file segment. I believe there is no possible overcommit in that case. But I would just suggest to disable memory overcommit in your entire system, thru `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`.

Comment: Michael explained exactly what I meant. I need to make it resident. I am trying to touch the memory but it segfaults. Any suggestions?